# Python requests check if success

Tags: python, request

I use the requests Module with python At the moment. I use "r.status_code == 200" to check if the response is valid. But for my project right now it gaves me false posetives. It would be better for me  to check if a response is valid with a Keyword check on the sourcecode or something like this is this possible ?

Comment: Check the documentation please.
https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content

Comment: Use `r.content` and check if the content contains whatever you're looking for

Comment: `r.contents` gives you bytes of the responses, `r.text` will give you it string/text form.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, its possible for your request to give you back empty or invalid data that is not useful to you.

Without knowing what this request return you could look for specific fields in the request, for example if the request returns a json look for specific fields using `if json_file.get("field_name", False)`